# Typescript extend class from typings

Tags: typescript

I have a library which I'm building with grunt. There's a class named `SearchResult` which is propertly exported in my 'd.ts' file:

```
declare module my.module {
    export class SearchResult {
        id?: string;
        object_type: string;
        item?: any;
        type?: string;
    }
}
```

And it's compiled to this:

```
357:[function(require,module,exports){
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var SearchResult = (function () {
    function SearchResult() {
    }
    return SearchResult;
}());
exports.SearchResult = SearchResult;
},{}]
```

But when I import this file using reference and trying to extend this class like that:

```
export class SearchResultChecked extends my.module.SearchResult {
    checked?: boolean;
}
```

I've got a runtime error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at __extends (_prelude.js:1)
```

There's many similar problems, but they're not the same.

`tsc -v`: 3.0.1

**UPD**: it lloks like I can't `extend` class which is not last defined in my library. Looking for solutions.

Comment: Are you literally using `declare module my.module`, i.e., an internal module (a.k.a. namespace), or are you using an external module with a quoted name?  Is the name `my.module` or `iqs.shell`?  If you have imports in the file with `SearchResultChecked`, please add them to the question.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen, It was compiled to `my.module`, like I named it. `my.module` and `iqs.shell` are the same, just forgot to rename for example. There's no imports in file with `SearchResultChecked` class, just a reference path in `tsd.t.ts`. Btw if I try to import some compiled js file with `SearchResult` it won't compile application because of `Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ShellStateName'`.

Comment: What do you mean that `SearchResult` was compiled to `my.module`?  Based on the output you quoted, it looks like an external module, and I don't see how that would get associated with the namespace `my.module`.  Maybe it would help to explain more about your build process.

Comment: Okay. I'm using gulp to build my module as... module. It gather all files into es5 module files (.js, .js.map, .css, .css.mad and .d.ts files). `.d.ts` file has a single module declaration with all interfaces and classes to export, and `.js` files contains compiled version. That I'm using this comiled module in another project, I'm including it in `typings/tsd.d.ts` file as a reference path. All services and components for angular works fine in that way, but classes like `SearchResult` are not.

Comment: Also, I can see `my.module.SearchResult` in my VS Code IDE, it compiled my application with `SearchResultChecked` class aswell, but error appears in runtime when I'm launch my application.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "es5 module".  Your build process must be doing something strange, but I'm not sure what.  If you delete all code from your project except the `SearchResult` and `SearchResultChecked` classes, does the problem still occur?  If so, please post the entire resulting `.js` file for `SearchResult` so I can see exactly what it's doing.

Comment: It looks like it's fine with just `SearchResult` in `my.module` and `SearchResultChecked` in application. Thats weird.

Comment: Ok. Problem occurs in `browser-pack` module in `_prelude.js` file.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen, I've got a details. Problem appears when there's files except `SearchResult` one next to this. It's ok if file in build process before `SearchResult`, but appears if it's next to it. Here's [normal](https://pastebin.com/TADGVk1s) and [failure](https://pastebin.com/SL9xu48N) versions of my library module.

Comment: Work on this problem has been continued at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52204725 .  I'll propose to close this question as a duplicate once the answer to the new question is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

`.d.ts` files are not emitted, they don't produce any code, and only exist on the type level (conceptually, at the linker level).

Code written in `.d.ts` files never makes it to runtime, it just tells TypeScript "assume that this class/enum/whatever is there, even though you aren't going to emit JS code about it"

If you want a class to actually exist in runtime, you will need to actually export it from an actual `.ts` file, or import a library that exposes the class.

Comment: I've added some details in comments above. I can extend class if there's no files prepends that one. I'm including my library and app js files at the page, so when my app.js files about to launch it already should know about library file.

Comment: Relying on execution order of files is fragile and is generally considered bad practice. This is why we have modules and module bundlers.