# Typescript: how to extend class from ts compiled library

Tags: typescript

I've seen a lot of similar questions but they're not the same as thi one.
I have a library compiled with `tsc` and I have an application. I'm including `library.js` and `app.js` in my `index.html`.
In `app.ts` I'm trying to extend class typed in `library.d.ts` and everything is okay util there's single class I want to extend to.

Here's link to [example library](https://github.com/Iworb/ts-library-extends-test) and [example application](https://github.com/Iworb/ts-application-extends-test). Steps to reproduce normal build and failure build included in description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the easy-to-follow steps to reproduce.  I figured out what is going on by reading the source code of the `pip-webui-tasks` build system you are using (it seems to be poorly documented).  `pip-webui-tasks` is based on Browserify.  Browserify takes a list of "entry point" files and bundles their dependencies, using the *last* entry point as the main module.  The main module is the only one whose exports will be available on `window.library`.  By default, `pip-webui-tasks` sets the list of entry points to be a list of all your source files in lexicographical order of the path.  In the normal build, the last source file in alphabetical order is coincidentally `src/services/index.ts`, so it becomes your main module and you get the behavior you want.  But when you add `src/services/other/other.ts`, that becomes your main module.

While the above is going on for the JavaScript bundle, the `.d.ts` file is written as if everything from all modules is exported, which is not true.  I'd consider this a bug in `pip-webui-tasks`.

Instead of relying on the default behavior of `pip-webui-tasks`, you'll need to specify your own list of entry points in `build.conf.js`.  You could list all your files with `src/services/index.ts` as the last, but it might be easier to specify just `src/index.ts` after ensuring it imports and exports everything you need.  I.e., you would add the following to `build.conf.js`:

```
browserify: {
    entries: ['src/index.ts']
},
```

and the following to `src/index.ts`:

```
export * from './services';
```

With these changes, the application loads up for me the same way as in the normal build.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it's brilliant and easy to understand. Build system I used simplify my build process so I decided to use it and didn't know about this pitfall.